# regex how to find filename which doesn't contain any numbers?

Tags: regex

I tried with `[^0-9].*` and `[^\d].*`
But none of them is working:
[image]

I only want to get filename which doesn't contain any numbers, in above case,
I need to get BUILDING.txt.

I also tried with 
[image]
But it only matches the characters instead of the whole filename.

Here is the online tool: https://www.regextester.com/

Tried with remove `.`

[image]

Comment: Try just removing the `.` from your first pattern

Comment: It says : ERROR: The expression can match 0 characters, and therefore match infinitely.    Here is the link to the online web: https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Weird error. Most engines don't consider 0 length matches to be an error. I recommend regex101.com instead. Either way, you can use a `+` instead of `*` as the quantifier: `[^\d]+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you might be trying to design an expression similar to:

```
^(?!.*\d).*$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/auzMiw/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/auzMiw/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
/^(\D*)$/gm
```

Hope it helps

François

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
^[^\d]+$
```

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S2M0F6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression should do the job. Since you've requested to only capture the filename of a file not containing numbers (this means only the filename and not the extension of the file).

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\.[a-zA-Z])
```

You can test the above regular expression here:

https://rubular.com/r/NMcMicEmLUKNTB